# Node.js: Write to database when page loads

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a link on the home page. Whenever user clicks on on the link and loads the page, I want to collect user-agent details and save it in the database.

I know it can be done easily with PHP with something like this:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('server', 'username', 'password');
    mysql_select_db('databasename');
    $cQuery = "insert into TRackTable (Source, Browser, Datetime) values (''" . mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET['q'])) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) . "', now())";
    mysql_query($cQuery);
    ?>
```

Is it possible with Node?
Or I have to collect all the information and post a request to node js server. Then write it to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple if you are using express.

Just use `req.headers['user-agent']` to access user agent information.

It will be easier if you install a Useragent NPM

https://github.com/biggora/express-useragent

Here is an example from GitHub Link

```
var http = require('http')
  , useragent = require('express-useragent');

var srv = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var source = req.headers['user-agent'],
  ua = useragent.parse(source);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(ua));

//ua JSON object has the user agent information that can be used to store in the DB
});
```

srv.listen(3000);

Comment: How would I get the user-agent at the server side? Link page is not hosted on node server. It is just a `href` on the page.

Comment: in that case you will have to post the information to node.js server